# Class has no instance getter - json model

Tags: json, flutter, dart, fetch

I am trying to solve a problem, which I cannot find any answer on by Googling it or in here, so here is my problem.

I am trying to fetch json data from my own json test server: http://my-json-server.typicode.com/tariksalihovic/innbo/receipt

The json data is nested, and i am trying to GET the `"receiptLines":` I have followed a tutorial for nested json data, but am not able to overcome the issue how to Print the `productNumber` string from a receiptLine.

As for my code i tried with `data[index].productNumber`, but i get the following error:

```
Class 'Receipt' has no instance getter 'productNumber'. Receiver: Instance of 'Receipt' Tried calling: productName
```

Please note that I am able to fetch and print the strings from the first level, but not second level.

Here is my full code, with the json model as well:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List> fetchData(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/tariksalihovic/innbo/receipt');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parseData, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List parseData(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map((json) => Receipt.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Lines {

  final String name;
  final String productNumber;

  Lines({this.name, this.productNumber});

  factory Lines.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Lines(
        name: json['name'],
        productNumber:  json['productNumber']
    );

  }

}

class Receipt {
  final int id;
  final String type;
  final String receiptId;
  final String orderNumber;
  final List<Lines> receiptlines;

  Receipt({this.id, this.type, this.receiptId, this.orderNumber, this.receiptlines});

  factory Receipt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    var list = json['receiptLines'] as List;
    print(list.runtimeType);
    List<Lines> receiptLines = list.map((i) => Lines.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Receipt(
        id: json['id'],
      type: json['type'],
      receiptId: json['receiptId'],
      orderNumber: json['orderNumber'],
        receiptlines: receiptLines
    );
  }
  }


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: fetchData(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ReceiptList(data: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReceiptList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List data;

  ReceiptList({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 26,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
            child: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          title: Text(
            data[index].type,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            data[index].receiptId,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700], fontSize: 12.0),
          ),
          trailing: Text(
            data[index].productName,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16.5,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no `productName` field in model class.

Comment: My bad, i ment `productNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Receipt.fromJson, change your current definition of receiptLines to:

```
List<Lines> receiptLines =
    List<Lines>.from(list.map((x) => Lines.fromJson(x))).toList();
```

Then, in your trailing text widget, you forgot to add "receiptlines" before productNumber, so it should be:

```
trailing: Text(
    data[index].receiptlines[index].productNumber,
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 16.5,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Very much appreciated! Thanks a lot! If there should be any better method to fetch nested json data or/and print it rather than data[index].receiptlines[index].string i would love to know.

Comment: No problem! Glad I helped. I'm sure there are ways to simplify down. I will have a look as well and tell you if I found any.

Comment: Hi again, thanks. I have stumbled on one more issue. My parser is only iterating through, the 1st lines of receiptLines, I have added more items, e.g. Id: 1 has 3 `receiptLines` each containing a  `name` and a `productNumber`. Instead of printing all lines it only prints the top 1 line and then iterating to the next Id: 2 and again printing the top 1 line in there.

Comment: How are you planning on displaying your receiptLines?

Comment: With a CustomScrollView In a SliverFixedExtentList - In my list the parrent json data would not be visible, only the child `receiptLines` id's. When clicking on a choice(e.g. receiptLine) then I will provide the neseccary parrent json data to that item.

Comment: If you use a listview for the receiptlines you can set the itemcount = data[index].receiptlines.length and change the index of this listview to anything but index.

Comment: Not sure if i understand that, i have defined itemCount as `itemCount: data[0].receiptlines.length` however if i replace 0 with index, it throws a error  "Error: The getter 'index' isn't defined for the class 'ReceiptList'." The good part is that I am able to iterate through the receiptLines, but only if I define which parrent e.g. 0,1 or 2.